# Display Classifier's Notes/Properties When Generating RTF in Sparx Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm using Sparx Enterprise Architect 10.

I have an instance of a Component on a diagram and I would like to display both:

- the instance's notes; and
- the classifier's notes

when generating RTF documentation.

If I have a package structure like this:

[image: Package Structure]

And have a template that publishes the Diagrams package and the elements on the package's diagram, I would like to get a result that looks like this:

[image: RTF Output]

It does not look like there is a field available for the classifier's notes -- only the name of the classifier. Do I have to do this with custom SQL?

**EDIT - April 25:**

Is anyone familiar with the SQL or script required to do this?

It looks like the only way to add a custom field to the report is using a fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that if I create a template fragment which displays the field that I want and use a custom query, I can get return the information that I want.

### Create the Template Fragment

Create a template fragment in Enterprise Architect.

- Only check the *Custom* checkbox in the *Sections* tree.
- Right click between the `custom` start and end tags on the page and choose *Insert Custom Field*.
- Type the name of the custom field (in this case, I chose to use `Notes`).
- Save, the click the *Document Options* icon.

[image: Template Designer]

### Set the Template Fragment Document Options

- Specify the SQL search string on the *Custom Query* tab.
- Note that the `Note` field must be aliased (`as Notes`)
- Ensure that the *Document Options* tab has *Template Fragment* checked.

The SQL that was needed is:

`select Note as Notes from t_object where object_id=(select classifier from t_object where t_object.object_id=#OBJECTID#)`

The *Custom Query* tab should look like this:

[image: Document Options Dialog]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, yes. You can go the other way and retrieve additional information from a classifier's instances, but not from an instance's classifier. The same is true in EA 11 (1105).